# Retry after exception without using the same list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, exception

I am trying to iterate over a list of values I have and want to retry if the program throws an exception. Basically I try to achieve this structure:

```
> for value in the list 
>     try:
>         do something A
>     except Exception:
>         retry A
```

I get it working that it retries after an exception however this is not 100% what I am trying to do. Is there any way to delete all entries from the list that were successful? If I have a list of 1,2,3,4,5 and it works for 1,2 just fine but throws an exception at 3, I want the program to retry 3,4,5 and ignore 1,2 completely. I know that changing a list I am iterating over is bad form, are there any alternatives?

Comment: You need a ``while loop`` with a conditional break.

Comment: Build a new list as you go

Answer (score 1):

**First option**

Have a list of values that need to be processing - if one fails, restart the iterations but over a smaller list.

```
vals = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

# processing 12 will fail the first time
first_try_12 = True

to_do = vals

while to_do:

    print("starting attempts...")
    for i, val in enumerate(to_do):

        try:
            if val == 12 and first_try_12:
                first_try_12 = False
                raise RuntimeError("blah")
            print("Did", val)
            
        except RuntimeError:
            print("barfed on ", val)
            to_do = to_do[i:]  # <== this is allowed - see below
            break

    else:
        to_do = []  # finished all iterations, so there is no more to do
```

gives:

```
starting attempts...
Did 10
Did 11
barfed on  12
starting attempts...
Did 12
Did 13
Did 14
```

BTW, regarding the assignment to `to_do` inside the except block, there need be no concern that it is modifying a list that we are iterating over, because: (1) it is not modifying the list (object), it is reassigning a name, and (2) we are about to break from the loop anyway.

---

---

**Second option**

Iterate over the list once only, but inside the `for` loop, retry each item until successful.

```
vals = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

# processing 12 will fail the first time
first_try_12 = True

to_do = vals

print("starting attempts...")
for i, val in enumerate(to_do):

    succeeded = False
    while not succeeded:
        
        try:
            if val == 12 and first_try_12:
                first_try_12 = False
                raise RuntimeError("blah")
            print("Did", val)

            succeeded = True
            
        except RuntimeError:
            print("barfed on ", val)
```

Gives:

```
starting attempts...
Did 10
Did 11
barfed on  12
Did 12
Did 13
Did 14
```

This is the same output as above except that the "starting attempts..." is only printed once.  So which option is preferable might depend on whether any initialisation needs to be done once only, or repeated when continuing after a failure.